# Using .preventDefault() with multiple events

Tags: jquery

How can I use `.preventDefault()` for every event below? Do I have to specify it for each event or can I do it another way?

```
$("h3 a").on({
click: function(){
    console.log("This is a click event");
},
mouseenter: function(){
    console.log("This is a mouseenter event");
},
mouseleave: function(){
    console.log("This is a mouseleave event");
},
dblclick: function(){
    console.log("This is a double click event");
}, function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // not working
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to specify for each event. Unless you have same handling code for each of those events, if yes.. then you could have it all in one function.

Comment: @Vega: Does that mean I can use: `$("h3 a").on("click mouseenter mouseleave dblclick", function(e){ e.preventDefault();});` ?

Comment: Yes, only if the implementation is same for all those events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach:

```
$('a').on('click mouseenter mouseleave dblclick', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on({
    click: function () {
        console.log("This is a click event");
    },
    mouseenter: function () {
        console.log("This is a mouseenter event");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        console.log("This is a mouseleave event");
    },
    dblclick: function () {
        console.log("This is a double click event");
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/btD5k/).

Though this *works*, it does feel rather verbose and, it would, probably, make sense to try and handle all the functionality in one common event-handler, perhaps triggering/calling different functions based on a switch statement, for example:

```
$('a').on('click mouseenter mouseleave dblclick', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'click':
            clickFunction(e);
            break;
        case 'mouseenter':
            mouseenterFunction(e);
            break;
            /* ...and so on... */
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/btD5k/1/).

Incidentally, JavaScript doesn't really distinguish between a `click` and a `dblclick` event, unless you measure the time between `click` events youself; so your event-handling is likely to be problematic.

Comment: This is neat. I never though of binding another click event like that.

Comment: I agree and it is one way but I would rather have it in all instead of adding a new handler.. but it could be just me.

Comment: @Vega, indeed: hence my *second* suggestion, which is basically the same as your own (though a coincidence, I promise...)

Comment: @DavidThomas haha.. my +1 for having both suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `e.type` inside a common handler.

```
$('a').on('click mouseenter mouseleave dblclick', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch(e.type) {
      case 'click': 
        console.log("This is a click event");
        break;
      case 'mouseenter':
        console.log("This is a mouseenter event");
        break;
      case 'mouseleave':
        console.log("This is a mouseleave event");
        break;
      case 'dblclick': 
        console.log("This is a double click event");
    }
});
```

I still don't recommend the above code, but just posting it in here as an alternate option.

My suggestion is to have the `e.preventDefault()` in each of the handler.

Comment: I will end up using e.preventDefault() in each handler, I was just curious. Thank you anyway.

Comment: And a reciprocated +1 for the same suggestion. :)